# retrieve uploaded images from the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I already got it to upload some images to the server, i am actualy saving the image to my user like this:

```
foto: { name: String, img: String, contentType: String },
```

so when i perform a get request, in angular i do a ng-repeat to get all my users, i want to display either the image related to the users.

get request:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/lojas')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.lojas = data;
        })
        .error(function (statusText) {
            $scope.lojas = [];
        });
```

here i get all the data even the path, but how can i acces the image here?

Comment: you uploaded the images that belong to the users, you have their paths. right? what do u mean by accessing? you need actual image objects not only paths?

Comment: hmmm, i really don't know i am a bit confused, but i want to do all in that get request above is the full path enough to get the image?

Comment: it depends on what you will do with image. After getting the image, what will you want to do?

Comment: just show nothing more like {{data.path}}

Comment: Then you just need the path

Comment: But in your case, it should be `{{lojas.path}}`

Comment: soo do i need to serve the static files here? and then acces that url? is that fine doing that?

Comment: Yes, You need to serve all your resource files which need to be display in html

Comment: fast question, how can i retrive the full path, i mean now i am retriving: upload/imageSrc, but to display i need to retrive localhost:8080/upload/imageSrc

Comment: I post the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serve your resource files (images, js, css, ...) in a static way.

Better to do this, put them in a subdirectory, then add this before server.listen

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/upload'));
```

(Assuming upload is the name of the folder containing your static files)

If the images are not saved with absolute path, you have to add `"window.location.href"` in front of the path name:

```
<img ng-src="{{window.localtion.href+data.path}}">
```

Comment: well i did this: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/upload')); since my upload files are inside the public folder, but i still cant get the image, i tried to see what {{loja.foto.img}} returned, it show me this: public\upload\9d23ad67119225b23be04c957111ee5b    any tipe?

Comment: do you have this file in ur server?

Comment: exactly, how can i save the image in node side with absolute path you know?

Comment: it should be something like this `var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();`, but I don't recommend you to save image with hostname, because it may change later and you have updated your database with new hotsname

Comment: ok, so that window.location.host\ sorry for my ignorance but where should i put that? in the controller side?

Comment: Sorry it was `.href` not `.host`

Comment: that will not work because my client side host is different from my server side

Comment: your client side requests to your server side, how can it be different? what are the hosts u have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135303/discussion-between-filipe-costa-and-imudin07).